# Interlacing two Node lists in java

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I posted a similar question but am still having issues am having an issue with trying to interlace two Node lists, i should be getting null according to my test case but it is giving a node containing "3D".

it seems the list continues on way longer than it should when I  look at it in debug mode in eclipse. tested my length method and it is returning the right length.

I don't understand why it seems my Nodes just keep on going, when it should only be a list of 13 nodes in the test case posted below.

the code should do the following For example {"KH","4C","8C","QC","3D","7D","JD"} becomes {"KH","4C","8C","QC"} {"3D","7D","JD"} (if as in this case the lists have an odd number of nodes then the first list is longer) and returns the list {"KH","3D","4C","7D","8C","JD","QC"}.

i have to solve this using the provided node class and cannot   use static  variables,  arrays  or  Java    collections. please don't just post code i really need to learn how to manipulate nodes but don't understand what i am doing is wrong.

```
public class ListShuffleExample {

public static Node<String> shuffle(Node<String> deck) {
    if (deck == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (deck.next == null) {
        return deck;
    }

    Node<String> lf = deck;
    int decklength = length(lf);
    int halflength;
    Node<String> first = deck;
    Node<String> second = deck;
    if (decklength % 2 == 0) {
        halflength = decklength / 2;

    } else {
        halflength = (decklength / 2) + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < halflength; i++) {
        second = second.next;
    }

    Node<String> curFirst = first;
    Node<String> curSecond = second;

    while (curFirst != null && curSecond != null) {
        // save the next one of the first list
        Node<String> nextFirst = curFirst.next;

        // set the next one of the first list to the first one of the second
        // list
        curFirst.next = curSecond;

        // save the next one of the second list
        Node<String> nextSecond = curSecond.next;

        // set the next one after the inserted item to the previous next of
        // the first list
        curSecond.next = nextFirst;

        // set the current references to the next ones
        curFirst = nextFirst;
        curSecond = nextSecond;
    }

    return first;
}

public static int length(Node<String> adeck) {
    int length = 0;

    while (adeck != null) {
        length++;
        adeck = adeck.next;
    }

    return length;
}
}
```

test cases

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ListShuffleExampleTest {
private static final Node<String> _AH = new Node<String>( "AH" );
private static final Node<String> _5H = new Node<String>( "5H" );
private static final Node<String> _9H = new Node<String>( "9H" );
private static final Node<String> _KH = new Node<String>( "KH" );
private static final Node<String> _4C = new Node<String>( "4C" );
private static final Node<String> _8C = new Node<String>( "8C" );
private static final Node<String> _QC = new Node<String>( "QC" );
private static final Node<String> _3D = new Node<String>( "3D" );
private static final Node<String> _7D = new Node<String>( "7D" );
private static final Node<String> _JD = new Node<String>( "JD" );
private static final Node<String> _2S = new Node<String>( "2S" );
private static final Node<String> _6S = new Node<String>( "6S" );
private static final Node<String> _TS = new Node<String>( "TS" );

private static <T> Node<T> makeList(Node<T>... nodes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length-1; i++) {
        nodes[ i ].next = nodes[ i+1 ];
    }
    nodes[ nodes.length-1 ].next = null;
    return nodes[ 0 ];
}
@Test
public void testReflection() {
    Class<?> iClass  = ListShuffleExample.class;
    for (Field field : iClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (!field.isSynthetic()) {
            fail( "class should not have any fields" );
        }
    }
}
@Test
public void testNull() {
    Node<String> actual = ListShuffleExample.shuffle( null );
    //expected: NULL
    assertEquals( "", null, actual );
}
@Test
public void testOddDivide10() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<String> input  = makeList( _QC );
    Node<String> actual = ListShuffleExample.shuffle( input );
    for (Object expected : new Object[]{ _QC }) {
        assertEquals( "Incorrect value", expected, actual );
        actual = actual.next;
    }
    assertNull( "Incorrect result", actual );
}
@Test
public void testOddDivide21() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<String> input  = makeList( _AH, _5H, _9H );
    Node<String> actual = ListShuffleExample.shuffle( input );
//                                           _AH,      _5H
//                                                _9H
    for (Object expected : new Object[]{ _AH, _9H, _5H }) {
        assertEquals( "Incorrect value", expected, actual );
        actual = actual.next;
    }
    assertNull( "Incorrect result", actual );
}
@Test
public void testEvenDivide22() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<String> input  = makeList( _2S, _6S, _TS, _AH );
    Node<String> actual = ListShuffleExample.shuffle( input );
//                                           _2S,      _6S
//                                                _TS,      _AH
    for (Object expected : new Object[]{ _2S, _TS, _6S, _AH }) {
        assertEquals( "Incorrect value", expected, actual );
        actual = actual.next;
    }
    assertNull( "Incorrect result", actual );
}
@Test
public void testOddDivide43() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<String> input  = makeList( _KH, _4C, _8C, _QC, _3D, _7D, _JD );
    Node<String> actual = ListShuffleExample.shuffle( input );
//                                           _KH,      _4C,      _8C,       _QC,
//                                                _3D,      _7D,      _JD
    for (Object expected : new Object[]{ _KH, _3D, _4C, _7D, _8C, _JD , _QC })   {
        assertEquals( "Incorrect value", expected, actual );
        actual = actual.next;
    }
    assertNull( "Incorrect result", actual );
}
@Test
public void testEvenDivide44() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<String> input  = makeList( _5H, _9H, _KH, _4C, _8C, _QC, _3D, _7D );
    Node<String> actual = ListShuffleExample.shuffle( input );
//                                           _5H,      _9H,      _KH,      _4C,
//                                                _8C,      _QC,      _3D,      _7D
    for (Object expected : new Object[]{ _5H, _8C, _9H, _QC, _KH, _3D, _4C, _7D   }) {
        assertEquals( "Incorrect value", expected, actual );
        actual = actual.next;
    }
    assertNull( "Incorrect result", actual );
}
@Test
public void testMany() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<String> input  = makeList( _AH, _5H, _9H, _KH, _4C, _8C, _QC, _3D, _7D, _JD, _2S, _6S, _TS );
    Node<String> actual = ListShuffleExample.shuffle( input );
//                                           _AH,      _5H,      _9H,      _KH,      _4C,      _8C,      _QC
//                                                _3D,      _7D,      _JD,      _2S,      _6S,      _TS
    for (Object expected : new Object[]{ _AH, _3D, _5H, _7D, _9H, _JD, _KH, _2S, _4C, _6S, _8C, _TS, _QC }) {
        assertEquals( "Incorrect value", expected, actual );
        actual = actual.next;
    }
    assertNull( "Incorrect result", actual );
}
}
```

Node class

```
public final class Node<T> {
public final T       value;
public       Node<T> next;

public Node(T _value) {
    this( _value, null );
}
public Node(T _value, Node<T> _next) {
    value = _value;
    next  = _next;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "" + value;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post the makeList method?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are forgetting to unlink the end of your first list from the beginning of your second list.

You expect the end of the list to point to `null` at the end, but instead, you leave a link back to the original start of the second list. When you have an even partition, then it works out because the last element was already `null` terminated. However, when you have an odd partition, you need to account for the extra element.

**Edit:** Your loop can terminate through a combination of two conditions: either `curFirst == null` or `curSecond == null` or both. You should think about what causes your loop to terminate, and which of those conditions must be true. Also, think about if there are any left over elements.

(You specifically asked for us to not post code!)

Comment: how can i set the last node of list 1 to point null for its next?, would i have to make a separate copy list and keep setting it to its next value till i got to the last node of the first list them set its next to null?